# how can i speed up my code?

Tags: python, json

It's a program that suggests to the user a player's name if the user made a typo. It's extremely slow.

First it has to issue a get request, then checks to see if the player's name is within the json data, if it is, pass. Else, it takes all the players' first and last names and appends it to `names`. Then it checks whether the `first_name` and `last_name` closely resembles the names in the list using `get_close_matches`. I knew from the start this would be very slow, but there has to be a faster way to do this, it's just I couldn't come up with one. Any suggestions?

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
def suggestion(first_name, last_name):
    names = []
    my_request = get_request("https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nfl/2016-2017-regular/active_players.json")

    for n in my_request['activeplayers']['playerentry']:
        if last_name == n['player']['LastName'] and  first_name == n['player']['FirstName']:
            pass

        else:
            names.append(n['player']['FirstName'] + " " + n['player']['LastName'])
            suggest = get_close_matches(first_name + " " + last_name, names)

    return  "did you mean " + "".join(suggest) + "?"



print suggestion("mattthews ", "stafffford") #should return Matthew Stafford
```

Comment: You may want to change `pass` to `continue` which tells the loop to start at the next value and run again.

Comment: How about persisting content of the [url](https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nfl/2016-2017-regular/active_players.json) on your local to reduce IO time?

Comment: Along the same lines as @OldPanda, implement a caching strategy.  Do you have access to something like memcached?

Comment: I'm thinking that using `names` instead of `suggest` might help. I'm not familiar with the module but it seems like `get_close_matches()` returns a `list`, so why not keep the operation on the same `list` object? That way your code won't have to compare the input with increasing number of candidates. So basically, `names = get_close_matches( ... ); return ... + "".join(names) ...`

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin That actually did the trick. Its lightening quick now (at least compared to earlier). I'll take a look into the other suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it turned out my suggestion in the comments worked out, I might as well post it as an answer with some other ideas included.

First, take your I/O operation out of the function so that you're not wasting time making the request every time your function is run. Instead, you will get your json and load it into local memory when you start the script. If at all possible, downloading the json data beforehand and instead opening a text file might be a faster option.

Second, you should get a set of unique candidates per loop because there is no need to compare them multiple times. When a name is discarded by `get_close_matches()`, we know that same name does not need to be compared *again*. (It would be a different story if the criteria with which the name is being discarded depends on the subsequent names, but I doubt that's the case here.)

Third, try to work with batches. Given that `get_close_matches()` is reasonably efficient, comparing to, say, 10 candidates at once shouldn't be any slower than to 1. But reducing the `for` loop from going over 1 million elements to over 100K elements is quite a significant boost.

Fourth, I assume that you're checking for `last_name == ['LastName'] and first_name == ['FirstName']` because in that case there would have been no typo. So why not simply break out of the function?

Putting them all together, I can write a code that looks like this:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

# I/O operation ONCE when the script is run
my_request = get_request("https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nfl/2016-2017-regular/active_players.json")

# Creating batches of 10 names; this also happens only once
# As a result, the script might take longer to load but run faster.
# I'm sure there is a better way to create batches, but I'm don't know any.
batch = []    # This will contain 10 names.
names = []    # This will contain the batches.

for player in my_request['activeplayers']['playerentry']:
    name = player['FirstName'] + " " + player['LastName']
    batch.append(name)

    # Obviously, if the number of names is not a multiple of 10, this won't work!
    if len(batch) == 10:
        names.append(batch)
        batch = []

def suggest(first_name, last_name, names):

    desired_name = first_name + " " + last_name
    suggestions = []

    for batch in names:

        # Just print the name if there is no typo
        # Alternatively, you can create a flat list of names outside of the function 
        # and see if the desired_name is in the list of names to immediately 
        # terminate the function. But I'm not sure which method is faster. It's
        # a quick profiling task for you, though.
        if desired_name in batch:
            return desired_name

        # This way, we only match with new candidates, 10 at a time.
        best_matches = get_close_matches(desired_name, batch)
        suggestions.append(best_matches)

    # We need to flatten the list of suggestions to print.
    # Alternatively, you could use a for loop to append in the first place.
    suggestions = [name for batch in suggestions for name in batch]

    return  "did you mean " + ", ".join(suggestions) + "?"

print suggestion("mattthews ", "stafffford") #should return Matthew Stafford
```